# Remove all files of a type (file extension) from whole directory tree

Tags: bash, find

I'm on macOS Sierra and I run in the terminal:

```
find . -name "*.css" -type f -delete
```

from the `src/app` folder and it doesn't delete from the whole directory tree, it only deletes from subdirectories one level down. This is the result:

[image: result of running the command]

**How do I make it delete css files in all subdirectories more than one level down?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you analyze time-stamps of those `css` files?

My first guess is that `css` files are auto-regenerated immediately after their deletion, from their `scss` source.
You can see if they get really deleted using a verbose deletion as follow:

```
find . -name "*.css" -type f -exec rm --verbose --interactive '{}' \;
```

And you can read their time-stamps using a simple `ls -l` command. I think it will show creation time-stamps closed to deletion time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are other possibilitys with other tools too. Here are two examples with preinstalled Debian tools. For more information regarding the tools and their switches look on the bash with "man".

This for deleting securely the files (go in the first folder):

> find . -name "*.css" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shred -fuzv -n 48

Or to delete files normally:

> find foldername -name "*.css" -type f -exec rm {} \;